# Design suggestion for pagination with a large number of pages.

Tags: overflow, pagination

I have a CMS site with Content Library where on pagination I show all the contents with pagination with each page showing 10 links. like.

```
<<First <<previous 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 next>> Last>>
```

I have this space restriction. things go fine until we land on a page where page number is like 1000 or 1500. There every thing goes above other and it looks bad can anybody give some suggestion.....

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [highest voted answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/789/pagination-best-practice/793#793) in the question linked to by the other answer suggests collapsing all the page links into an input field. I've seen this, but **scrolling a list and clicking a page number is a mouse-oriented activity**, so I've never been inclined to switch to the keyboard to enter a page number.  Perhaps the input could be a super-input that takes text or brings up a panel with page links (like most date field inputs these days), but I still think users wouldn't really know to expect anything better than having to type if they click on the box.

I prefer to use **smart truncation** to display the most helpful page links.  In other words, I show the **first 3**, `...`, the current page with a **padding of 3** (3 on either side), another `...`, then the **last 3**.  With a lot of pages, the links **above** the list look like this (the mouse is hovering over 56):

[image: Screenshot 1]

**Below** the list, I provide all links:

[image]

That would still be ridiculous to do if you had more than a couple hundred pages, but you could still provide more context on the bottom than on the top (increase the context of the current page to 100 or more).

Some other things to remember:

- **Use nice URLs**: `/myapp/mylist/16`
- Maybe you don't need pagination at all ("Show more..." or other endless list solutions).  In this case, a user uses **sorting** or **filtering/searching** to jump to data that is far down the list.
- Don't take up space with `First`/`Last` links if you already have a `1` and a `...[n]`, it's redundant and therefore not only space-wasting but also possibly confusing.
- If you were feeling inventive, the `...` could gain a box on hover and you could make it a button to bring up "more" pages in that range.
- You can always add a "Jump to: " quick input form next to your page links.

Comment: Good, thorough answer!

Comment: How does this work if the current page is 6 out of 58?   Would it be 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  ...  56  57  58 (i.e. only one set of dots)?   Or would it be 1  2  3  ...  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  ...  56  57  58 (i.e. consistent number of page numbers in each "part")?

Answer (score 4):

I think here you can find great answers for your question:
[Pagination Best Practice](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/789/pagination-best-practice)

Answer (score 0):

What I always do is give the user a decent chance to search/filter for his data, rather than make him figure out that the one record he's looking for is on page 6,712 of 13,568.

How often do you click on the "next page" when you search Google for example?  You don't, right?  If what you're looking for isn't on the first 10 hits, you refine your search.